# Use Props for child element style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React project I have a parent and a child component. I want to pass the props down and use those for styling in the child component.

Parent

```
<StyledToolbar>
   <Logo sx={{display: "block", width: 130}}  />
   ...
</StyledToolbar>
```

Logo.jsx

```
const Logo = (props) => {
    return (
        <img src="/assets/logo.svg"
             alt="My Logo"
             style={props.sx}
        />
    )
}
export default Logo
```

The logo is displayed but it is not styled correctly. Rendered HTML looks like this:
`<img src="/assets/logo.svg" alt="My Logo" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">`

Comment: [Works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cherry-w4ry6n?file=/src/App.js).  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: There's a section in [the MUI documentation on how to pass down the sx prop](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#passing-the-sx-prop).